# Fast Keyboard Macro (Root, Android Shell)

Tags: android, shell, macros, root, su

I've been working on an android Keyboard Macro App but I'm having difficulties in making it faster (type faster).
The program is for rooted apps and it works by using the shell command "input".

Method 1 (This is the faster one):

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
```

Method 2: (This is much slower due to the delay after the first input command)

```
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
input keyevent KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_A KEYCODE_ENTER;
```

I would like to type a large text as fast as possible, but having a shell script with "input keyevent" followed by a large combination of "KEYCODE_A" for instance, will not be executed. (Large Shell Commands are aborted)

Should I be using "sendevent"? How do i use it to type text?

My main objective is to type text/send keyevents as fast as possible.

Any Help is greatly appreciated.